# What exactly `semanticFormatterCallback` does in Flutter Slider?

Tags: flutter

I couldn't figure out what really `semanticFormatterCallback` do in bellow code. If possible, illustrate it with an example.

> The callback used to **create a semantic value from a slider value**.
>
> Defaults to formatting values as a percentage.
>
> This is used by **accessibility frameworks like TalkBack on Android** to
> inform users what the currently selected value is with more context.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MySliderApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MySliderApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MySliderApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MySliderAppState createState() => _MySliderAppState();
}

class _MySliderAppState extends State<MySliderApp> {

  var _dollars = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Sliders Demo'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Slider(
                  value: _dollars.toDouble(),
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  inactiveColor: Colors.pink,
                  label: '$_dollars dollars',
                  divisions: 100,
                  onChanged: (double newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _dollars = newValue.round();
                    });
                  },
                  semanticFormatterCallback: (double newValue) {   //<=======
                    return '${newValue.round()} dollars';
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`semanticFormatterCallback` enable you to customize what the app user will hear when adjusting the slider value (when TalkBack(android) or VoiceOver(iOS) is enabled)

By default the spoken text would be something like (5 percent, 10 percent) but without context it's hard to know what is the purpose of that slider

Checkout this video to help you understand this better
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12_3xglQrqf89O7lwIT3nNpUqtYu6mWBM/view?usp=sharing